# Angular 1.x ng-repeat shows data while straight template binding doesn't display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

This `ng-repeat` shows me data but not `{{ ...}}`

**ng-repeat**   WORKS

```
<div ng-repeat="x in confirm.booking.flightData">
    {{x.DestinationAirport}}
</div>
```

**Template Binding**  DOES NOT WORK

```
{{confirm.booking.flightData.DestinationAirport}}
```

is this because of the Arrays of data?

console.log shows this

```
confirm.booking > Object { flightData: Array[2], travelers: Array[1]
```

What I'm after is also going to be data in flightData Array Object 0

Picture below

example I was wanted to display data inside the `Segments`  per the picture,   Segments is an Array[2]

```
{{confirm.booking.flightData[1].Segments[0].FlightNumber}}
```

I don't believe the above will work, but based on the picture of my javascript object , what do I need to do?

[image]

Comment: Did you try <div ng-repeat="x in confirm.booking.flightData" ng-bind="x. DestinationAirport">   ?

Comment: *"is this because of the Arrays of data"* ... Yes...an array can't have a property like `DestinationAirport`. The objects inside the array in your case have that property

Comment: @EmilianoBarboza  What will ng-bind help me with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious that `{{confirm.booking.flightData.DestinationAirport}}` will not work as `flightData` is an *array*.

Did you check out `{{confirm.booking.flightData[1].Segments[0].FlightNumber}}` - becasue it will work. See a demo below:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.array = [{key:[1, {key: 'value2'},3]}, {key: 'value1'}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>{{array[0].key[1].key}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Per the other persons comment,  how can I maintain the angular/javascript data better?   I am not liking this  `{{confirm.booking.flightData[0].Segments[0].FlightNumber}}`

Comment: you should be using `ng-repeat` itself and display the data by using contextual conditions using `ng-if`, or *filters* like custom search filters / `limitTo` filter...

Answer (score 0):

1. If your ng-repeat loop is displaying data and the binding {{ }} is NOT, then yes you are simply not looking at the array.
2. Based on YOUR data, you seem to already have the answer!  You are not showing US all your segment data,  but if there is a `FlighNumber`  then

   ```
   {{confirm.booking.flightData[1].Segments[0].FlightNumber}}
   ```

SHOULD WORK !

You better be thinking about best practices as that is going to not be so awesome to maintain...

cheers

Comment: how can i maintain it better?